# Jquery dialog box URL value to be taken from property file

Tags: jquery

I have session invalidation code which will invalidate a user's session if he is idle for some time. Before invalidating the session I have to show a Jquery dialog box 1 minute before invalidating and ask the user if he wants to continue or logout.

Below is part of the code I have,

```
$j("#dialog").dialog({
buttons: {
'Yes, Continue': function()
 {
   $j.ajax({
    url: 'http://myDomain/session_extend.jsp',
```

Whatever code I have is working fine.

Problem is, I have 3 environments (Development, testing & Production). This code is there in my web application. Everytime there is a code change it has to be moved to Development, testing and Production. And everytime I need to change the domain in the above URL and deploy in respective environments.

Is it possible to take the URL value from some property file? Or are there any other means to solve my problem?

Comment: one way to solve is to use relative path. "/session_extended.jsp"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get your host name by using javascript like

```
var host = location.protocol+"//"+location.host+"/";
var pageUrl = host + "session_extend.jsp";
```

and you can pass this `pageUrl` in ajax `url` like

```
$j("#dialog").dialog({
  buttons: {
   'Yes, Continue': function()
   {
     $j.ajax({
       url: pageUrl,
```

I hope, It will help.

Comment: All the above answers worked. Even the one suggested by Senthil & Barmar

Answer (score 0):

You can use a relative URL:

```
url: 'session_extend.jsp',
```

If the calling page is in your development environment.